# User can see only part of receords

Tags: lookup, apex-managed-sharing

I have Project__c, Contact and User objects. User and Contact  are lookup to Project__c.  How to make the user see only those contacts that are in the same project where he is? I am trying Apex Managed Sharing (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm), but it will show all records. How to rescrict access to records that assigned to another project?

Update: I made sharing reasons, read access and private OWD. I am using Project__Share, so  it must be something a little different

Comment: What is the Org-Wide Default for Contact? What did you build in Apex Managed Sharing? That is certainly _a_ correct solution.

Comment: @DavidReed edited. I dont understand how to make visible only part of raleted object. I can make visible only procject in which users assigned, but  dont knwo how to do that with contacts.

Answer (score 1):

It appears from the information shown that you are adding the wrong share records, or missing adding additional share records.

In the data model shown, `Contact` does not inherit visibility from `Project__c`. If you're creating `Project__Share` records via Apex sharing, you are exposing `Project__c` records, but *not* `Contact` records. You would also need to create `ContactShare` records to do so.

Note that the Org-Wide Defaults for both objects must be `Private` and they must not be exposed to the user through some other vehicle, such as a Criteria-Based Sharing Rule or the role hierarchy, or you'll see results other than what you expect.

Comment: I think i get it. I must use Contact__Share and then through Project find the user I give read access?

Comment: Your Apex code would generate ContactShare records that provide access to each user associated with a given project for each contact on that project, if I understand your objective correctly. The Project record would help your Apex coordinate but wouldn't itself be referenced in the contact shares.

Comment: I still dont get why it will show only  necessary contacts, but i will try now.Thanks.